# Creation of the user management area in a BO by User Admin in a .Net7 MVC project with EF7 with Identity Account

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I'm developing a backoffice in .net 7 with EF7, with the default MVC template and Identity account.
I would like your help both in terms of code and opinion.
In my case, I don't need any more fields than IdentityUser has and as roles I'm going to have admin and editor. These roles I create directly in program.cs when I start the application and if they don't already exist I also create an admin user (in case there is a problem with the user, if it is deleted, when I restart the application it is created again).
Now I want to create a user management area where only admin users can access. There they can create/edit users. To block access to this area I use `[Authorize(Policy = "Admin")]`. Do you think that's enough?
How do I remove access or permanently disable access to the Registration page created by default at the start of the project, given that this page doesn't exist in the cshtml files and the user creation page I want to be for admin only and with a different name (probably)?
Do you think it's wrong, considering it's a backoffice, to create a user, generate a password randomly via code and send access via email?
Do you know of any repository that has an example similar to the one I'm setting up? I know I'm not inventing the wheel and that a lot of people have probably already been through this.

Answer (score 1):

add an admin route

```
//areas
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "areaRoute",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

create a BaseAdminController

```
[Area("Admin")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class BaseAdminController : Controller
{

}
```

all admin controllers should inherit from BaseAdminController

```
public class UsersController : BaseAdminController
    {}
```

link the controller with admin area

```
<a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Users" asp-action="index">Users</a>
```

or u can add admin just to users

```
 [Area("Admin")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
 public class UsersController : Controller
        {}
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late feedback.

It seems quite interesting and I think it's enough for what I want. So much so that I can do the same for the entire Backoffice so as not to leave any pages open. I can set Area=Admin or Editor as needed.
I log in and when I try to access the area I want, it sends me back to the login.

Comment: first make sure you have an admin role in AspNetRoles table. then check if the user you log in with has as  an admin RoleId -> UserId in AspNetUserRoles